# Como fazer um CountDown com jQuery que reinicia semanalmente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tenho que fazer um contador regressivo para uma promoção.

Eu preciso que esse contador reinicie toda terça-feira às 00:00 horas para que fique mais ou menos assim:

> "Restam apenas 6 dias 12 horas 42 minutos e 37 segundos para o fim da promoção"

Comment: Você precisa pegar a diferença entre o momento atual e a próxima terça...

Comment: Ideia interessante, porém não tenho experiência em jQuery, há uma forma de sempre pegar o timestamp da próxima "terça"?

Comment: Veja como marcar uma resposta como aceita em http://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Porque em jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//função para definir o dia destino e horário desejado para o final da promoção de cada semana
function dataDiaDaSemana(diaRef){
    var dias = {
        segunda: 1,
        terca: 2,
        quarta: 3,
        quinta: 4,
        sexta: 5,
        sabado: 6,
        domingo: 0
    };
    
    var dataAtual = new Date();
    var timestampAtual = dataAtual.getTime();
    var diaGatilho = dias[diaRef];
    var diaMilisegDif=0;
    var diaEmMiliseg = 1000*60*60*24;
    // adiciona um dia a diaMilisegDif enquanto o diaRef desejado (terca por exemplo) não for atingido
    while(dataAtual.getDay()!=diaGatilho){
        diaMilisegDif += diaEmMiliseg;
        dataAtual = new Date(dataAtual.getTime()+diaEmMiliseg);
    }
    return new Date(timestampAtual + diaMilisegDif);
}

//defina o dia destino da semana
var dia = dataDiaDaSemana("terca");
//defina o horario
dia.setHours(0,0,0,0); //(hora, min, seg, miliseg)


//fonte https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

//define a data para contagem regressiva
var countDownDate = new Date(dia).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
   if (distance < 1) { // você chegou ao seu destino :-)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  /*** redefine a data para próximo dia destino da semana *****/
  countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate.valueOf() + 604800000);
   }else if (days>0){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Restam apenas " + days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s para o fim da promoção";
 }else if (hours==0 && minutes==0){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Restam apenas " + seconds + "s para o fim da promoção";
 }else if (hours==0){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Restam apenas " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s para o fim da promoção";
 }else{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Restam apenas " + hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s para o fim da promoção";
 }
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

> Para um teste rápido coloque `var dia = dataDiaDaSemana("....");` sendo `....` o dia de hoje e em `dia.setHours(0,0,0,0);` hora atual e um minuto após o minuto atual exemplo, se são `12:25` coloque `dia.setHours(12,26,0,0);`

Comment: Perfeito, era isso mesmo que eu precisava, muito obrigado, de verdade, salvou meu dia kk

Comment: @DanielHirt para um teste rápido coloque `var dia = dataDiaDaSemana("sabado");` e em `dia.setHours(0,0,0,0);` hora atual um minuto apos o minuto atual exemplo, se são 12:25 coloque `dia.setHours(12,26,0,0);`

Answer (score 1):

> Tenho que fazer um contador regressivo para uma promoção.

```
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
```

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

> Eu preciso que esse contador reinicie toda terça-feira às 00:00 horas

Aqui você vai definir o limite do contador:

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();
```

Lembrando que isso é só o lado do cliente (front-end). Deve validar a data/hora do lado do servidor (back-end).

> [W3Schools: How TO - JavaScript Countdown Timer](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp)